# R - I want to extract the number after .O and .D in the given sample data in R. The number has varying length

Tags: r

Given below is the sample code. I need to extract the numbers after .O and .D which are varying in length.

```
ICM.CA.SMARTERTRAVEL.BOOKINGBUDDY.SEARCHBUTTONS_FLIGHT.PF.SOURCE45547.O84543558.D84543810.10884859

ICM.US.SMARTERTRAVEL.BOOKINGBUDDY.SEARCH-BUTTON_FLIGHT_TIER-5-LOW.PF.TAPARAMEBBGOOGLEUSSP_K134478116.O85783884.D85785680.20000060

ICM.US.SMARTERTRAVEL.BOOKINGBUDDY.SEARCH-BUTTON_FLIGHT_TIER-5-LOW.PF.SOURCE49394.O28970.D84670531.20000060
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    x <- "ICM.US.SMARTERTRAVEL.BOOKINGBUDDY.SEARCH-BUTTON_FLIGHT_TIER-5-LOW.PF.TAPARAMEBBGOOGLEUSSP_K134478116.O85783884.D85785680.20000060"


    t1<-sapply(strsplit(x, "\\.O"), "[", -1)
    t2 <- sapply(strsplit(t, "\\.D"), "[", -1)


    O <- sapply(strsplit(t1, "\\.D"), "[", 1)
    D <- sapply(strsplit(t2,"\\."),"[",1)
```

is this what you need?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_extract_all` from `stringr`.  It returns a `list` output.  We use the regex lookbehind (`?<=[.](O|D))`), which asserts that the numbers `[0-9]+` are preceded by a `.` followed by either 'O' or (`|`) 'D'.

```
library(stringr)
lst <- str_extract_all(x, '(?<=[.](O|D))[0-9]+')
lst
#[[1]]
#[1] "84543558" "84543810"

#[[2]]
#[1] "85783884" "85785680"

#[[3]]
#[1] "28970"    "84670531"
```

If there are multiple matches, it is better to keep it in the `list` format.  If the length of `list` elements are same, we can `rbind` them after converting to `numeric` class.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(lst, as.numeric))
```

#### data

```
x <- c('ICM.CA.SMARTERTRAVEL.BOOKINGBUDDY.SEARCHBUTTONS_FLIGHT.PF.SOURCE45547.O84543558.D84543810.10884859',
'ICM.US.SMARTERTRAVEL.BOOKINGBUDDY.SEARCH-BUTTON_FLIGHT_TIER-5-LOW.PF.TAPARAMEBBGOOGLEUSSP_K134478116.O85783884.D85785680.20000060',
'ICM.US.SMARTERTRAVEL.BOOKINGBUDDY.SEARCH-BUTTON_FLIGHT_TIER-5-LOW.PF.SOURCE49394.O28970.D84670531.20000060')
```